# Using JavaScript to hide a div placed in front of an iframe after clicking any link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div in the middle of my web page that is placed in front of an iframe the with links along side of it.  I would like to hide the div once any one of the links are clicked.  How would I go about doing this using javascript? I am very new to this so please be as descriptive as possible so that I can understand.

Here is some of my html code.  I have a number of links that appear in an iframe. I have the logo div positioned on top of the iframe and it loads when you enter the site.  However I want to hide the logo when you click on anyone of the links.

```
    <li><a href="resume.html" target="center table">My Resume</a></li></br>

    <li><a href="mycourseWork.html" target="center table">My Course Work</a></li></br>
```

I used the jquery code noted by Dolours below along with extra coding within my the body of my html code, when you click on a link then the div disappears as I intended but then it reappears once you click on another link. I want it to disappear and stay away. Here is the additional code that I came up with

About Me

Does anyone know how I can make my logo stay away?

Comment: assume id of the div is `block`, `$("#block").hide();`

Comment: Better show some part of html if you are completely new to javascript

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using jQuery:

```
// Get the iFrame jQuery Object
var $MyFrame = $("#iframeid");

// You need to wait for the iFrame content to load first
// So, that the click events work properly
$MyFrame.load(function () {
    var frameBody = $MyFrame.contents().find('body');

    // Find the link to be clicked
    var link = frameBody.find('.link_class');

    // Set the on click event for the link
    link.on('click', function() { 

         // Hide the div inside the iFrame
         $('#divID').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: On my site the iframe doesn't load until you click on a link.  To break up the awkward empty space I placed my logo in front of the iframe and the links are on the side of it.  I want to hide the logo only when any of the links are clicked because it would otherwise block content.  Here is what I was thinking   <script type= "text/javascript"> maybe using the function Hide() and the OnClick method with getElementById </java>  but I'm not sure everything that I try doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below

```
$('a').click(function() {    
  $('#divID').hide();        
});
```

Assuming all links will load the iframe.

Comment: I used the jquery code noted by Dolours along with extra coding within my the body of my html code, however when you click on a link then the div disappears but then it reappears once you click on another link. I want it to disappear and stay away. Here is the additional code that I came up with                             <div id="about"> 
<li><a href="about.html" target="center table" onClick="document.getElementById('logo').style.display=(document.getElementById('logo').style.display=='none')?'block':'none';">About Me</a></li>
</div>   Does anyone know how I can make my logo stay away?

Comment: $('a').click(function() {    
  $('#logo').remove();        
});

Comment: I ended up using the code that I noted above except I changed the part within the code noted as 'block' to hide and used no code within the head of my document. Instead I modified all of the links individually.  Here is what I came up with...                 <li><a href="my link to my iframe goes here" target="center table" onClick="document.getElementById('my div that I want to hide goes here').style.display=(document.getElementById('my div that I want to hide goes here').style.display=='none')?'hide':'none';">my link name goes here</a></li>  </div>